# Neovim plugin Fugitive isn't using the ssh key agent, so I can't Gpush/Git push

Tags: git, vim, neovim, ssh-agent, vim-fugitive

I am using Neovim on windows, as well as the vim-fugitive plugin. The plugin has a command that pushes commits, Gpush. I get an error saying "permission denied (publickey) fatal: could not read from remote repository. I am using an ssh key, everything works fine in a console but not with the plugin. I can't find anyone else with the same issue online.

Answer (score 0):

Try and launch Neovim from a CMD session where you have first typed:

```
set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tv"
```

That should generate more traces during the Gpush command, allowing to see *where* SSH is looking from its private/public key pair.

Comment: Didn't work for me on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @EthanFischer What version of Git do you have?

Comment: 2.25.1

Also I think the issue in my case was that I had initially pulled my repo from github using http. After removing the http remote and replacing it with the ssh one, everything works as expected

Comment: @Eth good call, well done.